# How to turn on network discovery for a specific network on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, network-shares, home-networking, network-discovery

I have two network adapters connecting to different networks A and B. I want to turn on network discovery for adapters/network B only but changing the setting in Network and Sharing Center seems to be a global switch for both networks. Is there a way to turn on network discovery for a specific network on Windows 10?

Comment: Setup A as Public and B as Private. That may work, otherwise the setting may be global as you surmise.

Comment: have you tried resetting the network adapter and then reconnecting it fresh to your network for the "first time" again? You should get a blue side menu that offers your device to be visible on that network where you can click yes or no... but I'm not sure if saying yes or no to this is just toggling the same global setting you speak of.